# Mouseover effect only on <i> in <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="cart">
 <a>
  <span></span>
  <i></i>
 </а>
</div>
```

And I have a mouseover effect when my mouse is over a `<a>` tag.
But I want to have a mouseover effect only on the `<i>` tag

This is my Javascript who adds the class "active":

```
$('#cart > .heading a').die('mouseleave').die('mouseover').die('mouseleave').die('click');
$('#cart').die('mouseleave').die('mouseover').die('mouseleave').die('click');
$('#cart').live('mouseover', function () {
    if (!$("#cart").hasClass('active')) {
        if (!Journal.isOC2) {
            $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
        }
        $('#cart').addClass('active');
        $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    }
});
```

Then I replace`#cart` to `#cart a i` everywhere

Without any success.

Answer (score 3):

I just remove the part `Journal.isOC2` And its working

```js
$('#cart a i > .heading a').die('mouseleave').die('mouseover').die('mouseleave').die('click');
$('#cart a i').die('mouseleave').die('mouseover').die('mouseleave').die('click');
$('#cart a i').live('mouseover', function () {
    if (!$("#cart a i").hasClass('active')) {
        
        $('#cart a i').addClass('active');
        $('#cart a i').live('mouseleave', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
Div
 <a> Anchor
  <span>Span</span>
  <i>Italic</i>
 </а>
</div>
```

Or you can also do like this with latest version of jquery

```js
$("#cart a i").on("mouseover", function(){
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
$("#cart a i").on("mouseleave", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
Div
 <a> Anchor
  <span>Span</span>
  <i>Italic</i>
 </а>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok it's worked for me too. Now only <i> have class="active". But now it don't have mouseover effect, maybe i need to change some .css file. Sorry. i'm not front end dev.

Answer (score 2):

> you can use css using your div tag css or I tag css

you can see below example for mouse-over effect

```css
.mainDiv i:hover{
color:red;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv" id="cart">main div
 <a> A tag
  <span>Span tag</span>
  <i>here is I Tag try to hover me</i>
 </а>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your HTML is not properly written. A `<a>` tag requires a `href=""` attribute, for compatibility with older browsers.

Also your javascript looks like it needs some simplicity.

```
$('#code a i').hover(
  function() {
   // ran when onmouseover
  },
  function() {
   // ran when onmouseleave
  }
);
```

Now implement your own code inside the function you see above.

Answer (score 1):

This is my ruff logic try this :

```
$( "a" )
  .mouseover(function() {
    $( this ).find( "i" ).addClass('active');
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $( this ).find( "i" ).removeClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also simplify your code to the following using latest jQuery (2.1.1).

```js
$(function () {
 $('#cart i').on('mouseover mouseleave', function (e) {
  if (e.type == "mouseover")
  {
   //if (!Journal.isOC2) $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
 .active {
  color: red;
 }
</style>

<div id="cart">
    <a>
        <span></span>
        <i style="border:1px solid black;">here</i>
    </а>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("i").hover(function(){
$(this).addClass('red')
$(this).mouseleave(function(){
$(this).removeClass('red')
})
})
})
```

```css
.red{
color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
 <a>this is
  <span>span</span>
  <i>italic</i>
 </а>
</div>
```